# PostgreSQL pgadmin backup - how to copy to file to local folder or my computer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have taken backup of PostgreSQL database Dev using pgadmin console selecting the database and using backup options.

Post successful backup message the backup.sql file gets saved.

We wanted to have this file downloaded locally. How we can download that file to local system? where these backup files saved?

Could you please help copying those files to local folders?

Comment: Do you realise you're basically asking how to copy a file? When the backup was created via pgadmin, you would have specified a location, which would generally be on the machine running pgadmin. If it's even possible for it to put the file elsewhere, then you just need to copy it to your machine...?

Comment: we don't have direct access to the server where pgadmin program is running. Only through pgAdmin console. Hence wanted to check if there is any way or mechanism on pgadmn tool where we can change the backup location or way to copy the file to local from the server. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're running pgadmin locally (connecting to remote server), then the backup file will already be on your local machine. If you're running pgadmin on another server, then the file will be there, and how you get it from that server to your machine is basically a question of "how do I copy a file". I'm not sure there's much more to say on this.

Comment: I totally forgot that I was running pgadmin on a Container with Docker. That's why I couldn't find the backup files on my machine!

Answer (score 7):

After you got your backup created go to the Processes tab (a link will be provided via the View Processes button in the popup notification).

Then click the View details button.
[image]

Go to Storage manager.
[image]

Select your file and click Download.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using Storage manager from the menu option Tools > Storage Manager
Once storage manager is open select required file and click download button as shown in @Eddir's answer